# Convert string("2015-03-24T12:31:33.8700000") to c# datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to convert a `string` with `date` to valid c# date time object.

```
input string example = "2015-03-24T12:31:33.8700000"
output c# datetime
```

I tried doing this

```
 DateTime.ParseExact(x.claimDetails.clmDOA, "yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Buit it gave exception

*`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`*

**Please Note**: I googled thoroghly .    Somehow i couldnt find any string
   with `"T"` included as in `datetime` string.

- Prior to downvoting if one can suggest me exactly where a question is answered with datetime string containg a `T` in it or of this format.`yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.fffffff`

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: Do we really want so many answers on a question that is as old as C# itself? I bet this is any duplicate

Comment: @HimBromBeere - but not of a Python question. This question is detailed and  needs an exact dupe with the ParseExact and the T etc.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Fair enough, but there is one I guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(example);
```

Comment: @SonerGönül In the example the date-time is in ISO format and in this case the culture is not important.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(example, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.fffffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Should work for you.

Comment: Errors - "DateTime pattern 'm' appears more than once with different values"

Answer (score 0):

From [`DateTime.ParseExact` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact);

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent. **The format of the string representation must
>   match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown**.

In your case, they are not.

You need to use `T` as a string literal delimiter, specify `:` as a [`TimeSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator) and seconds fraction (with [`fffffff` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#fffffffSpecifier)) as well.

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2015-03-24T12:31:33.8700000", 
                             "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff", 
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: What's the difference b/w this answer and other one posted by Arijit?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Since I used `InvariantCulture` as an `IFormatProvider`, I don't think those are the case in here. Of course there is no guarantee to not changing this culture in future but for now, it's ok.

Comment: Very true, I missed the `InvariantCulture`. Don't mind me :)

Comment: he gave an elaborated explanations and links for the user so that he can learn and stop posting these simple questions, where as My answer so was to solve the issue on urgent basis

Comment: @Rahul It uses `hh`, mine uses `HH`. Both can parse `12` but MSDN suggest always using wider ranges. Also little bit explanation as well.

Comment: @SonerGönül does hh & HH represents 12 and 24 hour format?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Yes, [`hh` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#hhSpecifier) represents 12-hour format from `01` to `12` but [`HH` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#HH_Specifier) represents 24-hour format from `00` to `23`

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I meant, I didn't knew the exact user requirement so gave the basic one :)

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(example , "yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: No, your format is not right.